# Upload Image within Wordpress Front-End Form via the Image's URL

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using the Board Game Geek API in order to pull in various data.  One piece of data I want is the image.

For example, here is an API call for a particular board game:
https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=169786&stats=1

When I get the response via my ajax call, I am able to grab the image url within the xml via:

```
var image_url = $(data).find("image")[0].textContent;
```

However: at that point I'm stumped.  I want to upload the image that is located at that url, but I do not know how to upload the image via a form.

In wordpress: the only way I know how to upload images is if the image *already exists* on my computer.  In that scenario, I have the following input:

```
<label for='board_game_image></label>
<input type="file" name="board_game_image" id="board_game_image" multiple="false"></input>
```

This input creates the "Choose Files" button to upload an image from your computer.  Once the form is submitted, I use [media_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) to save the image within the `uploads` directory and create the relevant database records.  Unfortunately: this process appears to not work when the image *does not* already exist on your computer, but instead exists somewhere on the internet (i.e. the image exists via the url).

**Question:** How can I upload an image via a wordpress front-end form when the image does not exist on my computer?  Instead: all I have is the `url` of where the image exists on the internet.

Comment: What do you mean by _"pull in"_? Do you want to display the image in a page or do something else with it? If the former, you can use `$('<img>').prop('src', imageUrl).appendTo('#some-container')`

Comment: @Phil I want to "upload" the image via a form.  For example: if the image existed on my computer, I would click the `input type="file"` button that says "Choose files", select the file I want to upload, and then submit the form.  The form then uses `media_handle_upload` to upload the image.  However: I do not think this is possible when the image does not exist on my computer.  Instead: the image exists somewhere on the internet.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Not sure, didn't come from me. Thanks for clarifying the question though

Comment: So you don't actually want them to upload the image but rather give the link to where the image is on some other platform?

If this is correct then all you need to do is to provide the user with a url input. Store this value in your DB and then call it to your template with the meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the image link on your form,

e.g.

```
var image_url = $(data).find("image")[0].textContent;
//assign the value to hidden input
$('#imgURL').val( image_url );
```

then add something like this on your form

`<input type="hidden" id="imgURL" name="imageURL">`

I'm not sure how you handle your form submission, but you can do something like below to process the image after submission.

First, save the image on uploads folder

```
$imgurl = $_REQUEST['imageURL']; // get the img url from the submitted data
$imginfo = pathinfo($imgurl); //get the url information 
$filename = $imginfo['filename'].'.'.$imginfo['extension']; // extract the image filename

$updir = wp_upload_dir(); // get upload directory
$uploadedfile = $updir['path'] . '/' . $filename; // create upload image location & file name

$image= file_get_contents( $imgurl ); // get the image actual content
$saved = fopen($uploadedfile, 'w'); // open the image file
fwrite($saved, $image); // write image conent
fclose($saved); // close image
```

Your image is now uploaded and stored on wp-content uploads folder, and the exact location is at `$uploadedfile`

However, the image is still not added on media library as it doesn't have any database entry connected to that image,

Now simply use [wp_insert_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) function to link that image into a database and it will show on media library,

just check that documentation and you'll see an example of linking `$uploadedfile` file to media library, you can do something like,

```
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

$attachment = array(
  'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
  'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$img_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadedfile );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $img_id, $uploadedfile );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $img_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: Wow!  I'll give you some additional points once the question is eligible for bounty! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

can you please check below code

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$imageurl = '<IMAGE URL>';
$imagetype = end(explode('/', getimagesize($imageurl)['mime']));
$uniq_name = date('dmY').''.(int) microtime(true); 
$filename = $uniq_name.'.'.$imagetype;

$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
$contents= file_get_contents($imageurl);
$savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $contents);
fclose($savefile);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => $filename,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
$imagenew = get_post( $attach_id );
$fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $imagenew->ID );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullsizepath );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data ); 

echo $attach_id;
```